# How do I use REPLACE in Asterisk to escape input

Tags: asterisk

I want to escape \ to \\ and " to \" in Asterisk. I've tried to use REPLACE but I can't get it to work. My current approach is as follows

```
exten => sms,1,Set(UNSAFESMSTXT=${REPLACE(SMSTXT,\\,\\\\)})
exten => sms,2,Set(SAFESMSTXT=${REPLACE(UNSAFESMSTXT,",\\")})
; Echo escaped input to terminal safely
exten => sms,n,System(echo "${SAFESMSTXT}")
```

When I send echo hi"echo hi, I get the error

```
ERROR[8239]: func_strings.c:804 replace: The characters to search for and the variable name must not be empty.
```

I use chan_mobile if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is nto cleat in function description?

```
Asterisk func REPLACE
Synopsis:
Replace a set of characters in a given string with another character.

Description:
Iterates through a string replacing all the <find-chars> with <replace-ch
ar>. <replace-char> may be either empty or contain one character. If empty,
all <find-chars> will be deleted from the output.
NOTE: The replacement only occurs in the output. The original variable is
not altered.

Syntax:
REPLACE(varname,find-chars[,replace-char])
```

You have use \" instead of "

Comment: I was a bit sloppy because I did not notice that you cannot replace 1 char with 2 chars. However I solved it by wrapping up the input between ' and ' whereby I replaced \' with \". Thanks for your help, your answer really helped. (Sorry for the late answer, my server died, so I had to switch some hardware).